# How find the norm $\|f_x\|$ of linear functional $f_x: C[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, normed-spaces

Consider the Banach space $C[a,b]$ with sup norm. For any fixed $x\in C[a,b]$ define $f_x(y)$ for any $y \in C[a,b]$ as follows:
$$f_x(y)=\int_a^b x(t)y(t) \; dt$$
Show that $f_x$ is a bounded linear functional and compute $\|f_x\|$.

I know that $f_x$ is a bounded linear functional and I am trying to show that $\|f_x\| = \|x\|_1$. How to make this? I know that $\|f_x\| \leq \|x\|_1.$ Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. Thank you much @Reveillark.